# Subset a dataframe based on quantiles

Tags: r, function, dplyr, subset

If I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(time = seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), length.out = 200, by = 'days'),
             a = rnorm(200,8.4, 22), b=rnorm(200,8.4, 22), d= rnorm(200,8.4, 22), 
e=rnorm(200,8.4, 22))
```

What would be the easiest way to subset this `df` so that the values from each columns should be higher than 10th% percentile but lower than 90th% one?

I could do this using a loop, i.e:

```
for (i in names(df[,2:5])){
  print(i)
  column <- df[,c('time', i)]
  q <- unname(quantile(column[,2], probs = c(0.1, 0.9))) # just for one column
  column <- column[column[,2] > q[1] &column[,2] < q[2],]
  df <- merge(df, column, by = 'time', all.x = T)
}
```

But there are more simple and more elegant ways to do that using functions or packages like `dplyr`. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I know. NA's can be inserted in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sapply` over columns and filter the values that are in the range.

```
sapply(df[-1], function(x) x[x > quantile(x, 0.1) & x < quantile(x, 0.9)])
```

To add `time` column back could be tricky as we have filtered the values every row potentially could be representing different `time`.

Better option as suggested by @Sotos is to convert those values to `NA` instead of filtering

```
cbind(df[1], sapply(df[-1], function(i) 
            replace(i, i < quantile(i, 0.1) | i > quantile(i, 0.9), NA)))
```

Comment: or to simply convert to NA, `sapply(df[-1], function(i) replace(i, i < quantile(i, 0.1) | i > quantile(i, 0.9), NA))`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I need the time column back since I need to complete some aggregations after this filtering.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(a:e), function(x) if_else(between(percent_rank(x), .1, .9), x, NA_real_))
```